# How do I animate the action bar during a layout transition?

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, transition

Is it possible to have an animation for the `ActionBar` on activity transition? I want to be able to make it bounce down just like the view layouts.

Comment: What you mean `animation for the animation on activity` ? I have Edited.

Comment: When I change from on activity view to the next activity view I want to be able to animate the action bar for the second activity. I can do it with the layout view but I can't find a good way to do it for the action bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following link will helps you alot.

### [Pushing the ActionBar to the Next Level](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/) from [Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/about/)